# c# Simple Injector inject decorator in a class only from one client

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Hy guys,
I have a problem, I have an interface like this:

```
public interface ICommand<in TRequest, out TResponse> 
    where TRequest : class
    where TResponse : BaseResponse
{
    TResponse Execute(TRequest request);
}
```

then I two class that implements this interface like this:

```
public class ExternalAddUser : ICommand<ExternalAddUserRequest, ExternalAddUserResponse>
{
    private readonly ICommand<AddUserRequest, AddUserResponse> _command;

    public ExternalAddUser(ICommand<AddUserRequest, AddUserResponse> command)
    {
        _command = command;
    }

    public ExternalAddUserResponse Execute(ExternalAddUserRequest request)
    {
        var response = _command.Execute(Mapper.Map<AddUserRequest>(request));

        return Mapper.Map<ExternalAddUserResponse>(response);
    }
}
```

and this:

```
public class AddUser : ICommand<AddUserRequest, AddUserResponse>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
    private readonly IDefaultSettings _settings;
    private readonly IMessageFactory _messageFactory;

    public AddUser(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMessageService messageService, IDefaultSettings settings, IMessageFactory messageFactory)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _messageService = messageService;
        _settings = settings;
        _messageFactory = messageFactory;
    }

    public AddUserResponse Execute(AddUserRequest request)
    {
        // My implementation here
    }
}
```

The Interface IMessageFactory is a "Factory/Template" Pattern that creates an IMessage interface with only property like: Body, Subject, Language. 
I have registered my class with simple injector like this:

```
container.Register(typeof(ICommand<,>), businessLayerAssembly);   
container.Register<IDefaultSettings, DefaultSettings>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Register<ISecuritySettings, SecuritySettings>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.RegisterConditional<IMessageFactory, ActivationMessageFactory>
            (c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(AddUser) 
                  || c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(SendActivationEmail));
container.RegisterConditional<IMessageFactory, RecoveryMessageFactory>
            (c => !c.Handled);
```

Now I have another class that is Decorator of ActivationMessageFactory like this:

```
public class ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory : IMessageFactory 
{
    private readonly IMessageFactory _messageFactory;

    public ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory(IMessageFactory messageFactory)
    {
         _messageFactory = messageFactory;
    }

    public IMessage CreateMessage(MessageData messageData)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

My question is:
Is possible to inject ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory  decorator in AddUser class when this class is called from ExternalAddUser class? 
Smell code example:

```
public class ExternalAddUser : ICommand<ExternalAddUserRequest, ExternalAddUserResponse>
{
    public ExternalAddUserResponse Execute(ExternalAddUserRequest request)
    {

        ICommand<AddUserRequest, AddUserResponse> command = new AddUser(new SqlUnitOfWork(), new EmailService(), 
            new DefaultSettings(), new ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory(new ActivationMessageFactory()));
    }
}
```

This is the object graph I wish to construct:

```
// AddUser injected into ExternalAddUser
new ExternalAddUser(
    new AddUser(
        new UnitOfWork(),
        new MessageService(),
        new DefaultSettings(),
        new ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory(
            new ActivationMessageFactory())))

// AddUser injected into anything else
new AnythingElse(
    new AddUser(
        new UnitOfWork(),
        new MessageService(),
        new DefaultSettings(),
        new ActivationMessageFactory())) // no decorator
```

Thank you for you answer, I hope i was clear.

Comment: Can we try about condition based injection based on consumer?

https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection

Comment: something like this 
`container.RegisterConditional<IMessageFactory , ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory >(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(ExternalAddUser));`

Comment: No, I've already tried it, but this solution doesn't work.

Comment: So your nesting your `ICommand` interfaces? That seems to be the source of your question. Take a look at [this](http://scrapbook.qujck.com/holistic-abstractions-take-2/)

Comment: My question is how to register this: `ICommand <AddUserRequest, AddUserResponse> command = new AddUser (new SqlUnitOfWork (), new EmailService (),
new DefaultSettings (), new ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory (new ActivationMessageFactory ());` ie, how to inject the decorator `ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory` in the class `AddUser` only when it is called from the specific class `ExternalAddUser` .I hope I was clearer. Thanks @Ric.Net

Comment: Is it possible to do it or do I have to find other ways? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why registering `ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory` as decorator over `IMessageFactory` (i.e. `container.RegisterDecorator<IMessageFactory, ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory>()`) won't work? Must that decorator be applied conditionally? And if so, with what conditions?

Comment: Yes, the decorator ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory() must be conditionally applied to the ActivationMessageFactory() class only when the AddUser command is called from within the ExternalAddUser class.

Comment: In practice I should have two graphs, this:
`new ExternalAddUser (
        new AddUser (
         new UnitOfWork (),
         new MessageService (),
         new DefaultSettings (),
         new ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory (
             new ActivationMessageFactory ())))` 
and this:
`new AddUser (
         new UnitOfWork (),
         new MessageService (),
         new DefaultSettings (),
             new ActivationMessageFactory ()))`. Thank you very much @Steven and congratulations for the excellent work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is to apply a decorator based on the consumer's consumer. This can't be easily achieved in Simple Injector. Instead, you can try the following: Instead of making the decorator conditional, inject it with contextual data that can be set by the start of the request. This way the decorator can decide whether or not its logic should be executed, or it should simply forward the call to its decoratee.

**UPDATE**:

You can define the following abstraction:

```cs
public class ICommandContext
{
    Type RootRequest { get; }
}
```

This abstraction allows you to check what the type is of the root request that is currently running. You can use this abstraction inside your decorator:

```cs
public class ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory : IMessageFactory 
{
    private readonly ICommandContext _context;
    private readonly IMessageFactory _messageFactory;

    public ActivationMessageWithoutLinkFactory(
        ICommandContext context,
        IMessageFactory messageFactory)
    {
        _context = context;
        _messageFactory = messageFactory;
    }

    public IMessage CreateMessage(MessageData messageData)
    {
        if (_context.RootRequest == typeof(ExternalAddUser))
        {
            // Begin decorated stuff
            var message = _messageFactory.CreateMessage(messageData);
            // End decorated stuff

            return message;
        }
        else
        {
            return _messageFactory.CreateMessage(messageData);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside your Composition Root, you can now create an `ICommandContext` implementation and a `ICommand<,>` decorator that can manage this context:

```cs
public class CommandContext : ICommandContext
{
    public Stack<Type> Requests = new Stack<Type>();

    public Type RootRequest => Requests.First();
}

public class ContextCommandDecorator<TRequest, TResponse> : ICommand<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    private readonly CommandContext _context;
    private readonly ICommand<TRequest, TResponse> _decoratee;
    public ContextCommandDecorator(
        CommandContext context,
        ICommand<TRequest, TResponse> decoratee)
    {
        _context = context;
        _decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    public TResponse Execute(TRequest request)
    {
        _context.Push(typeof(TRequest));

        try
        {
            return _decoratee.Execute(request);
        }
        finally
        {
            _context.Pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you can add the following three registrations to your application:

```cs
container.Register<ICommandContext, CommandContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<CommandContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommand<,>), typeof(ContextCommandDecorator<,>));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but How can I do for "inject it with contextual data that can be set by the start of the request."? Have you got any example?

Comment: Do note that I feel that Ric's assessment is right. You might not run into these kinds of problems when you don't nest your commands and take a close look at your design, althpugh this is not something I can prove.

Comment: Hi Steven, I tried your solution and it works perfectly. Only for code correctness, the RootRequest must be taken with the Last () method otherwise the last type inserted in the stack would be taken, the Pop and the Push should be used on the read-only property Requests and the control in the decorator should always be done on the type of request. I tried to correct it but it was rejected. Thanks a lot. @Steven